# Wifi adapter not found in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have tried a lot to connect my WIFI on ubuntu16.04. WiFI detection slowly died out. Not sure if it is problem of my system or ubuntu related issue. Any help is much appreciated

```
lspci -vnn | grep Network

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [17aa:21ce]
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj and welcome to askUbuntu! Please add the output of follwing command to your post: `hwinfo --netcard`

Comment: What is "your Wi-Fi"? Is it a PCI or USB adapter?

Comment: Output for `sudo lshw -C network` and `nmcli device show`.